# jQuery - Check If Objects Match Between Sets By Common Property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to look for either a JavaScript OR a jQuery solution that would ensure that each set/array of objects both share the same VALUE of a property - in this particular case, two items share the same guid value between both sets, but some properties are different - like, one object has a property that the other object in the other set does NOT have. In this sense, `JSON.stringify` would definitely NOT help my case, since it is comparing the data sets as an absolute string literal.

Can someone show me how this can be done? Like, consider the two sets below:

Set One

```
[  
   {  
      "currentApptTime":"/Date(1557759600000)/",
      "endApptTime":"/Date(1557761400000)/",
      "allDay":true,
      "patientName":null,
      "subjectPrsnlId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "gCalEventId":"2pqfikpmtccp2954dk5m8a2u6i",
      "patientPhone":null,
      "patientEmail":null,
      "preferredContactMethod":null,
      "apptConfirmItems":null,
      "id":"19d8b079-aa62-4038-a2f5-8927d46013f1",
      "ART":0,
      "openTime":"/Date(1557805950000)/",
      "closeTime":null,
      "Active":false,
      "summary":"Ice cream",
      "description":"No lemonade",
      "updateTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "userUpdateId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "externalAppId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "userOpenId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "userCloseId":null,
      "userOwnerId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "TimesUpdated":0,
      "expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "masterTicketItems":[  

      ],
      "IsAppt":""
   },
   {  
      "genLogItems":null,
      "id":"2cebb82e-08ec-40a7-ad6d-8169cfdd500e",
      "ART":90,
      "openTime":"/Date(1558065783000)/",
      "closeTime":null,
      "Active":true,
      "summary":"We do another thing",
      "description":"It be great",
      "updateTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "userUpdateId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "externalAppId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "userOpenId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "userCloseId":null,
      "userOwnerId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "TimesUpdated":0,
      "expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "masterTicketItems":[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      "genLogItems":null,
      "id":"e4019eb7-ec76-4e82-ae5f-65ea428b47f6",
      "ART":77,
      "openTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "closeTime":null,
      "Active":true,
      "summary":"Duck",
      "description":"Time to duck",
      "updateTime":"/Date(1557807323000)/",
      "userUpdateId":"ae40e68b-c76c-4bf6-a87c-fa899a98f6f9",
      "externalAppId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "userOpenId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "userCloseId":null,
      "userOwnerId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "TimesUpdated":6,
      "expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "masterTicketItems":[  
         {  
            "ticketItemId":"1eaa0a80-c4f2-4567-ab35-70c1687c0daa",
            "createTime":"/Date(1557807307000)/",
            "Active":false,
            "updateTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
            "userCreatedId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
            "userUpdateId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "userOwnerId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "itemType":"Another Log",
            "itemDescription":"Let's just add this",
            "timesUpdated":0,
            "expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
            "actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "genLogItems":null,
      "id":"dddcf2ac-b212-4ae2-ae79-62f1da904982",
      "ART":161,
      "openTime":"/Date(1563939862707)/",
      "closeTime":null,
      "Active":true,
      "summary":"Pouffet",
      "description":"Generally Speaking",
      "updateTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "userUpdateId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "externalAppId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "userOpenId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "userCloseId":null,
      "userOwnerId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "TimesUpdated":0,
      "expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "masterTicketItems":null
   },
   {  
      "genLogItems":null,
      "id":"ff2551b2-eb19-4d0b-920a-a52027b87ef3",
      "ART":180,
      "openTime":"/Date(1563946670018)/",
      "closeTime":null,
      "Active":true,
      "summary":"How did Constatinople",
      "description":"Get the works",
      "updateTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "userUpdateId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "externalAppId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "userOpenId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "userCloseId":null,
      "userOwnerId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "TimesUpdated":0,
      "expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "masterTicketItems":null
   }
]
```

Set Two

```
[  
   {  
      "genLogItems":null,
      "id":"2cebb82e-08ec-40a7-ad6d-8169cfdd500e",
      "ART":90,
      "openTime":"/Date(1558065783000)/",
      "closeTime":null,
      "Active":true,
      "summary":"We do another thing",
      "description":"It be great",
      "updateTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "userUpdateId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "externalAppId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "userOpenId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "userCloseId":null,
      "userOwnerId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "TimesUpdated":0,
      "expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "masterTicketItems":[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      "genLogItems":null,
      "id":"e4019eb7-ec76-4e82-ae5f-65ea428b47f6",
      "ART":77,
      "openTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "closeTime":null,
      "Active":true,
      "summary":"Duck",
      "description":"Time to duck",
      "updateTime":"/Date(1557807323000)/",
      "userUpdateId":"ae40e68b-c76c-4bf6-a87c-fa899a98f6f9",
      "externalAppId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "userOpenId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "userCloseId":null,
      "userOwnerId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "TimesUpdated":6,
      "expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "masterTicketItems":[  
         {  
            "ticketItemId":"1eaa0a80-c4f2-4567-ab35-70c1687c0daa",
            "createTime":"/Date(1557807307000)/",
            "Active":false,
            "updateTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
            "userCreatedId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
            "userUpdateId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "userOwnerId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "itemType":"Another Log",
            "itemDescription":"Let's just add this",
            "timesUpdated":0,
            "expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
            "actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "genLogItems":null,
      "id":"dddcf2ac-b212-4ae2-ae79-62f1da904982",
      "ART":161,
      "openTime":"/Date(1563939862707)/",
      "closeTime":null,
      "Active":true,
      "summary":"Pouffet",
      "description":"Generally Speaking",
      "updateTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "userUpdateId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "externalAppId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "userOpenId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "userCloseId":null,
      "userOwnerId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "TimesUpdated":0,
      "expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "masterTicketItems":null
   },
   {  
      "genLogItems":null,
      "id":"ff2551b2-eb19-4d0b-920a-a52027b87ef3",
      "ART":180,
      "openTime":"/Date(1563946670018)/",
      "closeTime":null,
      "Active":true,
      "summary":"How did Constatinople",
      "description":"Get the works",
      "updateTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "userUpdateId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "externalAppId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "userOpenId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "userCloseId":null,
      "userOwnerId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "TimesUpdated":0,
      "expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "masterTicketItems":null
   },
   {  
      "genLogItems":null,
      "id":"19d8b079-aa62-4038-a2f5-8927d46013f1",
      "ART":181,
      "openTime":"/Date(1563946809157)/",
      "closeTime":null,
      "Active":true,
      "summary":"Ice cream",
      "description":"No lemonade",
      "updateTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "userUpdateId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "externalAppId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "userOpenId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "userCloseId":null,
      "userOwnerId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc",
      "TimesUpdated":0,
      "expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/",
      "masterTicketItems":null
   }
]
```

From these two sets, there is a JSON object in each one that has the SAME "id" value:

```
19d8b079-aa62-4038-a2f5-8927d46013f1
```

Here's the JSON object with that ID in question from Set One:

```
{"currentApptTime":"/Date(1557759600000)/","endApptTime":"/Date(1557761400000)/","allDay":true,"patientName":null,"subjectPrsnlId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","gCalEventId":"2pqfikpmtccp2954dk5m8a2u6i","patientPhone":null,"patientEmail":null,"preferredContactMethod":null,"apptConfirmItems":null,"id":"19d8b079-aa62-4038-a2f5-8927d46013f1","ART":0,"openTime":"/Date(1557805950000)/","closeTime":null,"Active":false,"summary":"Ice cream","description":"No lemonade","updateTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/","userUpdateId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","externalAppId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","userOpenId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc","userCloseId":null,"userOwnerId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc","TimesUpdated":0,"expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/","actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/","masterTicketItems":[],"IsAppt":""}
```

Annnnd here's the JSON object with the same id from Set Two:

```
{"genLogItems":null,"id":"19d8b079-aa62-4038-a2f5-8927d46013f1","ART":181,"openTime":"/Date(1563946809157)/","closeTime":null,"Active":true,"summary":"Ice cream","description":"No lemonade","updateTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/","userUpdateId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","externalAppId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","userOpenId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc","userCloseId":null,"userOwnerId":"c4c75afb-2916-40c4-ac0f-74b98a43a8cc","TimesUpdated":0,"expectedCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/","actualCompletionTime":"/Date(-62135575200000)/","masterTicketItems":null}
```

Note, however, that these two JSON objects share the same ID, but different *properties.* `JSON.stringify` would say, "These two objects are not the same because some of their properties and values are different." If there's something I'm failing to understand about that, please let me know.

How would I ensure that these data sets, given the guids matching, are asserted to be the same, even though some of the other properties or values are different in these objects? My problem is not that I want to compare JUST two objects from the array - I want to only care that the objects are the SAME on a given property. I hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about [mcve]

Comment: If I understand your question correctly. You want to get the values of set One and set Two and then compare them, don't you? Why don't you just do that?

Comment: @GentleSama, please read my edited question. Tell me if there's something I need to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
let setTwo = [
  {
    'id': '11',
    'location': 'New York'
  },
  {
    'id': '12',
    'location': 'Paris'
  },
  {
    'id': '14',
    'location': 'Berlin'
  }

]

let setOne = [
  {
    'id': '11',
    'language': 'English'
  },
  {
    'id': '12',
    'language': 'Fernch'
  },
  {
    'id': '13',
    'language': 'German'
  }
]

setOne.forEach(function(element, position) {
  if (setOne[position].id === setTwo[position].id)
  {
    console.log('hurray');
  } else {
    console.log('ohhhh');
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes. You got it.

Comment: I guess when I think about it now though I could use the map function?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with the map function. You'd have to do some research.